# Template instantiation error in msvs 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to create a compile time structure that maps messages to default processors, but my code fails to compile in msvs 2015 update2. I think it's a bug in the compilator as a code is quite legimate and compiles with gcc. Below you can see minimal example reproducing the problem

```
#include <tuple>

struct About;

struct PluginStub
{
    static void About();
};

template<typename Sink>
class Processor
{
    template<typename Call, typename Stub, Stub Pointer>
    struct Method;

    using Methods = std::tuple<Method<About, decltype(&PluginStub::About), &PluginStub::About>>;
};
```

This gives such output:

```
1>  main.cpp(25): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'unknown-type'
1>  main.cpp(25): note: Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
1>  main.cpp(26): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Processor<Sink>' being compiled
```

Questions:

- Am I right about bug in msvs?
- How to workaround this problem?

Comment: @Cody Gray. In the same template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to use `std::decay`:

```
using Methods = std::tuple<Method<About, 
                           typename std::decay<decltype(&PluginStub::About)>::type, 
                           &PluginStub::About>>;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why does this help?

Comment: @sliser sure, as second argument you need the type of a pointer to function. Most probably in the `decltype` of vc++ has strings attached, this is where `std::decay` comes in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Indeed this is a bug. I created a ticket https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2822978/template-instantiation-error-in-msvs-2015
2. Another way to workaround this bug is to move
   Methods definition out of class Processor scope.

P.S Everything compiles just fine if Processor isn't a templated class