# 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'intptr_t' with boost.dll

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on plugin system using [Boost.dll](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html)

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp>
#include <memory>

class base {
public:
  base(){};
  ~base(){};
  template <typename T>
  static std::shared_ptr<base> create() {
    return std::make_shared<T>();
  }
  virtual void do1() = 0;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
  derived(){};
  ~derived(){};
  virtual void do1() override {}
};

BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(base::create<derived>, // <-- this function is exported with...
                create_plugin          // <-- ...this alias name
)

// auto a = base::create<derived>();
```

When I trying use factory method inside BOOST_DLL_ALIAS macro getting error like below.

> ```
> cl /c /ID:\Download\Compressed\boost_1_67_0 a.cpp
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25834 for x86
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> a.cpp
>
> a.cpp(27): error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'intptr_t'
>
> a.cpp(27): note: Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
> ```

Without BOOST_DLL_ALIAS macro when calling factory method (as shown in last commented line), it get compiled fine.

Comment: Please include all text generated by the compiler not just the part you think is important.  The notes/extra information is often key.  Also, [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93381d152fc017f0): what is your exact compiler version and flags?

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/WJkv_1

Comment: @YSC can repro: https://godbolt.org/z/fDLsi3 (with MSVC) /cc Adam

Comment: @Borgleader well done. So once again, MSVC is broken...

Comment: Stab in the dark: put `()`s around `(base::create<derived>)`.  (Theory: preprocessor is doing something messed up)

Comment: Yes I think so, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50904d080de0d8b9 Seems working fine.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont No luck with  `(base::create<derived>)`

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277547/directly-casting-from-pointer-to-a-template-function) no longer applicable?

Comment: @ManthanTilva So far I like the solution with the std::function, but in lack of the rest of your code, I cannot be fully sure it serves what you needed as a whole. Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// this really does nothing:
template<class R, class...Args>
R(*to_fptr( R(*f)(Args...) ))(Args...) {
    return f;
}
// except avoid the bug in MSVC:
BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(to_fptr(base::create<derived>),
            create_plugin
)
```

that should fix it.

MSVC seems to break when you try to cast from the name of a template function to a intptr_t.  This is a bug.

The above workaround changes it from directly dealing with the name of a template function to just a function pointer.  By breaking the overload resolution and the cast to intptr_t apart, MSVC no longer chokes.

You could probably also do:

```
template<class T>
T identity( T t ) { return std::move(t); }
```

instead of `to_fptr`.

`to_fptr` is a function that takes a function pointer and returns it.  The syntax to return a function pointer from a function is a bit ridiculous, which is why it is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(std::function<std::shared_ptr<base>(void)>(base::create<derived>), // <-- this function is exported with...
    create_plugin          // <-- ...this alias name
)
```

Indeed it seems MSVC has a bug here, as there should be no problem taking such an expression `base::create<derived>` and treating it directly as a function pointer. So instead, we "feed it a function pointer" ourselves using the magic of std::function.

I've chosen to use `std::function` as it involves no writing of any kind of wrapping code and relies directly on intent-delivering standard c++ code.

And of course don't forget to `#include <functional>` : )

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860819/template-instantiation-error-in-msvs-2015) tangentially related answer, I found another solution:

```
const void * create_plugin =
    reinterpret_cast<const void*>(
        reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(
            reinterpret_cast<std::decay_t<decltype(&base::create<derived>)> >(
                &base::create<derived>
            )
        )
    );
```

https://godbolt.org/z/NVGz_0

Comment: This makes me want to do a `#define DECAY_TO_VALUE(...)` macro to remove the DRY.  Also, that decay cast should be a `static_cast` I think.

Comment: Yeah, probably. I just found the triple `reinterpret_cast` hilarious. On that note, just a single `reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&base::create<derived>)` apparently makes MSVC happy, too. Then again, I have no idea what casting to `intptr_t` first would accomplish in the first place.